# Javascript: ignore alt-characters

Tags: javascript, iframe, keypress, event-listener

I have an iframe (with designMode set to on) within a page that has a keypress listener in it.  The keypress function listens for certain alt-character keystrokes, but I never want these alt-characters to actually show up in the iframe. How can I tweak my function so that these characters aren't passed through to the iframe's content?

```
function keyPress(e)
{
  if(e.charCode == 402) //option f
  {
    //code to do stuff

    //prevent character from passing through to content?

  }
}
```

Comment: Handling the alt key won't be sufficient. What if I paste these characters in?

Comment: well the goal isn't so much to keep those characters out, I just want an alt key to serve as a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `event.altKey` to check whether `alt` is pressed. Then, use the `preventDefault()` method to prevent the default behaviour, and `stopPropagation()` to stop the event bubble.

```
function keyPress(e) {
    if(e.altKey){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }
    ....
```